# Covering most of a view with an overlay Android

Tags: android, overlay, transparency, intersection

When covering a view with an overlay I am aware that I need to use a FrameLayout, and the child views stack on top of each other. Setting a view to having a background with opacity will create the overlay effect. However, in my situation, I am required to create a hole in my overlay to display the contents of a tab item / other views beneath it. This is where I am stuck.

I am not sure how to perform the intersection on the view so that it is transparent in a specific area of the view (which I need to determine based upon the position of a specific View element (Tab, ImageView, etc).

[image]

The image above shows the result I want to achieve. With the entire view having an overlay on it, besides one of the Tabs and the Info box (which needs to move based on the view displayed through the overlay).

I believe I need an intersection of the views to achieve the result I need...this is something I am not sure about. Can someone point me in the right direction of a solution please, I do not expect to be just given a solution, its all about learning!

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JakubHolovsky Not as yet. It is something to do with intersections, I have to get this to work too.

Comment: Hmm. Do you trying to write some kind of step by step guide for your application ? There are libraries which already do that...